# Is there a one-line perl equivalent to: sed -n -f multipatternfile textfile?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I've been searching for hours for a one-liner perl command to put in a script that will do multipattern replacements read from a file similar to sed.

Trying to do a perl one-liner multipattern search replace on a textfile using multipattern file:

textfile:

```
apples bananas oranges
blueberries walnuts granola
```

multipatternfile:

```
s/blueberries/chocolate/p
s/bananas/raisins/p
```

Using sed I could do this one-liner:

```
$ sed -n -f multipatternfile  textfile
apples raisins oranges
chocolate walnuts granola
```

Using perl I tried this one-liner:

```
$ perl -pi -F multipatternfile  textfile
syntax error at multipatternfile line 2, near "s/bananas/raisins/p"
Execution of multipatternfile aborted due to compilation errors.
```

But the perl version chokes at the second pattern no matter what I have in there for the second pattern.

Is there something wrong with the way I have the pattern file formatted?

Before you ask, I cannot use sed because sed has no non-greedy regex.

Comment: Have you tried `sed -P`? Some versions of sed support Perl-like regexes.

Comment: Out of interest - why do you need it to be a one liner? If you've a pattern file, could you not have a perl script instead?

Comment: @nooodl Yes.  And you run into this famous sed error:
sed -n -r -f /tmp/testpatterns /tmp/testfile
sed: file /tmp/testpatterns line 2: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Sobrique because I don't want to maintain a perl script.  I'm looking for a one-liner.

Comment: @androidin What do you think "multipatternfile" is? A banana?

Comment: @androlin: Why is that a *famous `sed` error*? You should be using `$1` on the RHS, not `\1`

Comment: @Borodin from the GNU sed manual: Backreferences must still be escaped when using extended regular expressions. \1 is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out:

multipatternfile:

```
s/blueberries/chocolate/p;
s/bananas/raisins/p;
```

With perl you need to have semicolons at the ends of the patterns:

```
$ perl -p multipatternfile textfile
apples raisins oranges
chocolate walnuts granola
```

Comment: Part of the reason I asked is because that _is_ a Perl script. Or very nearly. But as long as you have something that meets your needs, fair enough.

Comment: This is incorrect. `-F` specifies the autosplit pattern if you are using the `-a` switch. When you don't use `-a`, the `-F` switch is unused. You might as well use only `-p`. Or if you want to be fancy, just add `while (<>) { s/..../; print; }` and you dont need any switches at all, and you would have one of those horrid "perl scripts".

Comment: Also, the `/p` modifier is unlikely doing what you think. This is the description from `perldoc perlop`: `p When matching preserve a copy of the matched string so that ${^PREMATCH}, ${^MATCH}, ${^POSTMATCH} will be defined.`

Comment: @TLP -F noted, revised the answer.
/p: although not necessarily for this example I want all the matches.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The problem with the original example was that the pattern file needed to have semicolons.  The -F switch was a NOP and didn't affect the result.  And the same with /p.  With or without keeping the matches the result is the same here.

Comment: Like I said, it's unlikely doing what you think. You say "I want all the matches", well, that's not what `/p` does. That is what `/g` does, it replaces as many times as it can, instead of just once.

Comment: /p is preserving the match, the part of the string before the match and the part of the string that comes after the match.  I always preserve these because they are useful.  And of course /g is "apply to all matches". Only been doing regexes for 35 years.